# how to call rest API in WP for custom routing

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to wordPress, I have a doubt that how to call rest API in WP for custom routing, can any one please provide sample or give me suggestions that how to do this, any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

please try [ADDING CUSTOM ROUTES TO THE WORDPRESS REST API](http://torquemag.io/2015/06/adding-custom-routes-wordpress-rest-api/)

Answer (score 1):

Make first a Virtual link :

```
 //Add a Virtual Links
    add_action( 'init', 'wpse9870_init_internal' );
    function wpse9870_init_internal()
    {
      global $wp_rewrite;

        $wp_rewrite->add_external_rule( 'my-api.php', 'index.php?api=1', 'top');
    }

    add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse9870_query_vars' );
    function wpse9870_query_vars( $query_vars )
    {
        $query_vars[] = 'getrequest';
        return $query_vars;
    }

    add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpse9870_parse_request' );
    function wpse9870_parse_request( &$wp )
    {
        if ( array_key_exists( 'getrequest', $wp->query_vars ) ) {
            include 'my-api.php';
            exit();
        }
        return;
    }
```

After that you can write your code on my-api.php for restApi and your request url is: http://siteURL.com/?getrequest